# position relative not working in IE9 and lower versions

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have one image and that is getting showed as per below CSS

```
#imaged{
    display:inline;left:-220px;position:relative;bottom:-40px;
}
```

In Chrome, it is displaying as per bottom and left position. 
But in IE, the image is getting displayed '-40px' downwards. Buy if i do css as

```
#imaged{
    display:inline;left:-220px;position:relative;bottom:0px;
}
```

then it works in IE but not in Chrome then..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check any default element stylesheets, e.g. margins.

Comment: there are not any default styles sheets

Comment: I am trying with sample div. It is working fine. Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/f4km3pj8/